# Taken the average

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to take the average of sum points that can be `NULL` in some cases.

This is the only way that I can do it:

```
(points(11)+points(14)+points(15)+points(16))*100/(120)
```

But this formula ignores the `NULL` values. How should I change the code to meet the requirement?

Comment: What is mean by points?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (((SUM(points))*100)/count(points))
FROM table
```

If you have an ID or a field that you want to sort by you can use this

```
SELECT id, 
(((SUM(points))*100)/count(points))
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```